# Poner CDATA a XML

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, xml, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con `VB.NET` he convertido un archivo `XSD` a clase para crear un archivo `XML`, pero tengo la necesidad de poner un `CDATA` al valor de un nodo.

```
Dim note = New NoteType()
    Dim noteArray = New List(Of NoteType)
    note.languageLocaleID = "1000"
    note.Value = New XElement("Note", New XCData("CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100"))
    noteArray.Add(note)
    invoice.Note() = noteArray.ToArray()
    EscribirXML(invoice)
```

Escribiendo el XML

```
Sub EscribirXML(invoice As InvoiceType)
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InvoiceType))
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("D:\XSD\Stack\factura.xml")
        serializer.Serialize(writer, invoice)
        writer.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Como resultado me esta saliendo lo siguiente: "Un string sin la marca del CDATA"

```
<Note languageLocaleID="1000" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100</Note>
```

El resultado que espero es el siguiente

```
<cbc:Note languageLocaleID="1000"><![CDATA[CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100]]></cbc:Note>
```

[image: CDATA]

Saludos!

Comment: No entiendo tu problema, no te deja guardar un cdata?

Comment: @gbianchi Si ese es el problema no me deja guardar(poner) un CDATA en un archivo XML que estoy creando, el primer problema es que a la variable note no le puedo asignar un valor es ahí donde debe ir el CDATA, pero creo que lo debo poner vació porque creo que el CDATA se pone cuando se lee el archivo en memoria y se pone el CDTA en el nodo indicado? ó se puede poner cuando estoy construyendo el XML? tengo esa duda también

Comment: No debe ser Set(value as string) ?

Comment: No entiendo tu edicion. Donde pones aca tiene que ir el cdata, simplemente agrega el nodo cdata que creaste antes, y crealo como lo puse en la respuesta. Lo porbaste asi?

Comment: @gbianchi Si lo probé pero no ha funcionado, ya logre poner el CDATA cargando el archivo, solo me falta crear el nodo para ponerlo donde corresponde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifica el getter/setter de tu clase para usar un clase auxiliar que (des)envuelva el valor en CDATA:

```
...
    Private _Note As String
    Private _Note_ As NoteElement

    <XmlElement()>
    Public Property Note As NoteElement
        Get
            Return New NoteElement(_Note)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As NoteElement)
            Me._Note_ = value
        End Set
    End Property

...

Public Class NoteElement
    <XmlAttribute()>
    Public languageLocaleID As Integer = 1000

    Private _Note as String

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(note As String)
        _Note = note
    End Sub

    <XmlText()>
    Public Property Value As XmlNode()
        Get
            Return New XmlNode() { New XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(_Note) }
        End Get
        Set(value As XmlNode())
            _Note = CDate(value(0).Value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Si no puedes heredar las clase serializadora puedes agregar el nodo así:

```
Dim xmlIndex As New XmlDocument()
xmlIndex.Load("D:\XSD\Stack\factura.xml")
Dim root As XmlNode = xmlIndex.DocumentElement

Dim cdata As XmlCDataSection = xmlIndex.CreateCDataSection("CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100")
Dim noteElement As XmlElement = xmlIndex.CreateElement(cdata)
noteElement.SetAttribute("languageLocaleID","1000")
root.AppendChild(noteElement)
```

Comment: Hola seguí parte de tu respuesta, la parte de la propiedad Note no la puedo implementar en mi clase que la cree desde un XSD, porque al modificarla no la puedo serializar, pero si cree una clase auxiliar que si funciona, una pregunta como puedo limpiar parte del nodo XML que me devuelve?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Note xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" languageLocaleID="1000"><![CDATA[CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100]]></Note>`

Comment: Necesito sacar la primera <> y dentro de <Note necesito sacar  ´xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema´

Comment: Intenta heredando la clase creada a partir del XSD. ¿Cómo usas la clase auxiliar?

Comment: `Dim xmlIndex As New XmlDocument()
        xmlIndex.Load("D:\XSD\Stack\factura.xml")
        Dim root As XmlNode = xmlIndex.DocumentElement

        Dim mc As Note = New Note
        mc.MyString = "CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100"
        Dim serializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(Note))
        'Dim elem As XmlElement = xmlIndex.CreateElement(mc.ToString)

        Dim writer As StringWriter = New StringWriter
        serializer.Serialize(writer, mc)
        root.AppendChild(writer)
        xmlIndex.Save("D:\XSD\Stack\factura.xml")`

Comment: De donde sacas NoteElement?

Comment: @Pedro: Agregué un código basado en tu ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias ya esta solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

El tema viene por acá:

```
Dim cdata As XCData = <![CDATA[CIENTO  OCHENTA Y  CINCO CON 00/100]]>
```

Eso esta bien, pero no le tenes que pasar un string...

Le tenes que pasar un nodo XCData, que se crea usando lo siguiente:

```
XmlDocument().CreateCDataSection(TuValor);
```

De esa forma, el nodo queda con un valor XCData

Comment: Lo que hago es crear el XML, según el código que proporcionas es cuando termine de crear el XML y lo cargue de la ruta donde esta y leer nodo a nodo hasta ponerlo en el nodo indicado?, no es posible ponerlo a la hora que estoy creando el XML?

Comment: Esto es a la hora de crear el xml... cuando le agregas ese nodo

Comment: Voy a modificar la pregunta siendo mas explícito de como creo un nodo y como debo crear el siguiente nodo.

Comment: ¿Cuando pones XmlDocument es por que primero vas a declarar una propiedad con ese tipo de dato y vas a cargar el xml pasandole la ruta donde se encuentra?

Comment: @PedroÁvila no te entiendo. Vos preguntaste como crear un nodo Cdata y yo te escribi como crear ese tipo de nodo. Luego, lo podes agregar al xml en el momento que quieras y en el lugar que quieras.

Comment: XMLDocument es un objeto de ese tipo.